# How to add 'delete' icon to a UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage

My app requires an image uploader which either takes an image from the user's iphone photo library or directly from the camera.

My question: How can I add an 'delete' icon to the top left hand corner of the image (as seen in the screenshot below)?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.You have to create a *UIButton* with the close image and position it at the top left corner of the image manually.

2.You can also create a *UIImageView* with the close image, adding a *UITapGestureRecognizer* to it, and position it at the top left corner.